# PowerShell run script locally - Execute actions remote

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I need some help to execute a script remote. What i want to do is to connect to a remote server and import a .psm1 with commands.
The problem seems to be that Powershell looks for the files in the users path on the computer that is executing the script. I also copied the script to a network share but I get the same result executing there.

Script.ps1

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName servername.domain.com -Credential domain\admin.account –ScriptBlock {

#!! Microsoft MDT Section !!
# Import Microsoft MDT commands
#Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.BDD.PSSnapIn
Import-Module –name .\MDTDB.psm1
#
#Connect to MDT database
Connect-MDTDatabase –sqlServer servername.domain.com –database DATABASE

#Import file with settings to add servers to database
#$vms = Import-Csv InputServerInfo.csv
$machines = Import-Csv .\InputServerInfo.csv
#
# Script commands goes here
}
```

Error message:

```
The specified module '.\MDTDB.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (.\MDTDB.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
    + PSComputerName        : servername.domain.com

The term 'Connect-MDTDatabase' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Connect-MDTDatabase:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    + PSComputerName        : servername.domain.com

Could not find file 'C:\Users\admin.account\Documents\InputServerInfo.csv'.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Import-Csv], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand
    + PSComputerName        : servername.domain.com
```

I tried with both Invoke-Command and New-PSSession but I can't get it to work. I also rember something about Dot Source that loads the script in memory before executing but I'm not sure about this.

I really would appriciate some pointers for this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Give a full unc path to the module that is accessible to the remote computers

```
Import-Module \\server\share\MDTDB.psm1
```

Comment: When I try that I get the following error: get-itemproperty : Cannot find path 'H:\-' because it does not exist. At \\servername\share\MDTDB.psm1:130 char:26 + $mdtProperties = get-itemproperty $drivePath + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (H:\-:String) [Get-ItemProperty], ItemNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand Seems that Powershell somehow want my localy mapped H:\ drive to exist on the server also?

Comment: You got past the first hurdle since it is loading the module now.  How is $drivepath being set?  You need to find what is passing h:\ to it